# How to add cors settings in IIS rewrite with authorization?

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to create a rewrite rule in IIS. I want ro send requests to mydomain.com, but using authorization.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="api">
                    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.com/api/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_Authorization" value="Basic c13546tYW4uaASWJh79864L=" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
          <outboundRules>
              <clear />                
              <rule name="api">
                  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                      <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(.*)" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
              </rule>           
          </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is working. But when I send a request using javascript ajax, it throws exception. (my javascript app is running on 'http://127.0.0.1:1265')

> from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:1265' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field authorization is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml](https://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml).

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule matches too many requests so you have to modify it to at least exclude all CORS preflight requests, because according to the standards those preflight requests must be anonymous and without authorization header (like the error message indicates).

Comment: But example.com requires basic authorization. How can I change it?

Comment: @barteloma to weaken a rule and exclude certain requests, add a `condition` tag.